# Wait for ... after page load before initiating animation jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, delay

I wrote a script using jQuery so that a page automatically scrolls to a certain id tag when the page loads. I want this animation to wait 5 seconds after the page loads before it triggers. How can I do this?

Here is the script I wrote:

```
let scrollAnchor = "anchor-scroll"

const scrollToAnchor = function(anId){
  let aTag = $("#"+anId)
  console.log(aTag);
   $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: aTag.offset().top }, 12000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  scrollToAnchor(scrollAnchor);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use `setTimeout(function() { scrollToAnchor(scrollAnchor);}, 5000);`. In your `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .delay() function.
All is here -> https://api.jquery.com/delay/  ;)